# Node.js - Aggregate retorna objeto

Tags: node.js, mongodb, join

Estou fazendo localmente o exercício de Node.js como MongoDB proposto em https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb_join.asp

Há duas coleções, **orders** e **product**.

Após a agregação, o resultado esperado seria:

```
[
  { _id: 1, product_id: 154, status: 1, orderdetails: [
    { _id: 154, name: 'Chocolate Heaven' } ]
  }
]
```

Porém, na minha instância local, estou obtendo o seguinte:

```
 [ { _id: 1, product_id: 154, status: 1, orderdetails: [ [Object] ] } ]
```

Há algum truque para que o **[Object]** seja mostrado como **{ _id: 154, name: 'Chocolate Heaven' }** ?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Para mostrar o resultado esperado, é necessário usar JSON.stringfy():

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mydb";

MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    db.collection('orders').aggregate([
        {
            $lookup:
            {
                from: 'products',
                localField: 'product_id',
                foreignField: '_id',
                as: 'orderdetails'
            },            
        }
    ], function (err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
        db.close();
    });
});
```